# Return values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following structure

```
   const objArray = [ { shiftId: 89192 },
       { shiftId: 89193 },
       { shiftId: 89190 } ]
```

An array of objects.
I am trying to map over and extract the value of the `shiftId`

What I do is
`object.map(el=> Object.values(el));`but this mapping returns the following structure because `Object.values` returns an array unfortunately.

```
[ [ 89192 ], [ 89193 ], [ 89190 ] ]
```

Nested arrays with only one element.
How can I map over this to only back an array.

Comment: please add a valid data format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the `shiftId` property, just specify that you want to extract that particular property, rather than using `Object.values`:

```
const shiftIds = object.map(({ shiftId }) => shiftId);
```

Note that you have an *array* there - your code would be more understandable if you called the variable `arrOfShiftObjs` or something like that, rather than calling it `object`.

To extract multiple values from each item and put them into a single larger array, use `flatMap`:

```js
const arr = [{
    shiftId: 89192,
    id: 'id'
  },
  {
    shiftId: 89193,
    id: 'id'
  },
  {
    shiftId: 89190,
    id: 'id'
  }
];
const values = arr.flatMap(Object.values);
console.log(values);
```

Or, if the objects also contain other properties that you don't want to include, and you only want `shiftId` and `id`:

```js
const arr = [{
    shiftId: 89192,
    id: 'id'
  },
  {
    shiftId: 89193,
    id: 'id'
  },
  {
    shiftId: 89190,
    id: 'id'
  }
];
const values = arr.flatMap(({ shiftId, id }) => [shiftId, id]);
console.log(values);
```

Like the use of all newer functions, if you want to support browsers which don't have it yet, use a polyfill. Of course, you could also `reduce` instead

```js
const arr = [{
    shiftId: 89192,
    id: 'id'
  },
  {
    shiftId: 89193,
    id: 'id'
  },
  {
    shiftId: 89190,
    id: 'id'
  }
];
const values = arr.reduce((a, { shiftId, id }) => {
  a.push(shiftId, id);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works... but why, can you explain? How do we get only the value back instead of the whole object for example?

Comment: `Object.values` returns an array of *all values* in the object, in the form of an array. If there's only one key-value pair in the object, it'll return an array containing one value. If you `.map` and the callback returns something from `Object.values`, you'll get a nested array as you see. So, just don't use `Object.values` if you want to extract just one property from the object - that way, the `.map` callback returns the *plain value* you're interested in, rather than an array. (you could also return `Object.values(el)[0]` if you don't know the key value beforehand)

Comment: What if we wanted to do the same but the object had shiftId and Id and we needed both, what coudl we do in that case?

Comment: What'd be your desired output in that case? Still just a single array containing numbers?

Comment: Yeah, let's say a normal array.

Comment: Use `arr.flatMap(Object.values)`

Answer (score 0):

You could get the property from the first found value.

```js
var array = [{ anonymous: { shiftId: 89192 } }, { anonymous: { shiftId: 89193 } }, { anonymous: { shiftId: 89190 } }],
values = array.map(o => Object.values(o)[0].shiftId);

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Object destructuring and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let array = [{ anonymous: { shiftId: 89192 } }, { anonymous: { shiftId: 89193 } }, { anonymous: { shiftId: 89190 } }]

let out = array.map(({anonymous: {shiftId}}) => shiftId)
console.log(out)
```